# Rewriting SQL IN statement with long list of parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

These IDs seem like they should be a table as, there are several queries that use the same list of IDs.  The following needs to be refactored.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.TypeID IN(1,2,3,4,7,8,10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Sales s
```

The problem is a subquery can't be used in an aggregate function.  I'd like to write it as follows, but it causes an error:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.TypeID IN(SELECT ID FROM SaleTypes WHERE SaleType.Desc = 'US') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Sales s
```

Comment: If this code is in an aggregate function, it might be better to include the whole `CREATE FUNCTION` code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the poster pasted just the relevant snippet and this is merely one column of many.  For that purpose, I would prefer an outer join.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN st.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM Sales s
  LEFT JOIN SaleTypes st
         ON (s.TypeId=st.ID AND st.Desc='US')
```

Comment: Very observant :-) the example I gave was incredibly simple, there are several counted columns in the query.

Comment: All good solutions. I guess its not possible to get this as concise as I would like. Thanks.

Comment: A convoluted `sum(case when x then 1 else 0)` is far inferior to a simple `count`.

Comment: @janos Mmm, I'm not sure "SELECT count(st.ID)" and the implicit null check is safer.  Tends to get lost in the maintenance and replaced by "SELECT count(*)."

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `SUM`, each record has a value of either 1 or 0. The value is 1 if some condition is true for that record, and 0 if false. In other words, you're really *counting* the records where the condition is true.

The condition appears to be, `Sales.TypeID` should be one of `1,2,3,4,7,8,10`. And if I understood it correctly, these correspond to the ids of the `SaleType` records where `SaleType.Desc = 'US'`.

It sounds like you want to join the `Sales` and `SaleTypes` tables,
where `Sales.TypeID` match `SaleTypes.ID`,
and `SaleType.Desc = 'US'`.
So this query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Sales s 
JOIN SaleTypes st 
ON s.TypeID = st.ID 
WHERE SaleTypes.Desc = 'US'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Nitpicks**

SQL code (like pretty much all code) reads a lot easier when using line breaks and indentation.

---

`s` is not a very good alias. You want your aliases to say something about what it means, not just shorten the code. In this case I would not even use one, I feel `Sales` is plenty short.

---

Your code so far:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN Sales.TypeID IN(1,2,3,4,7,8,10) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
) 
FROM Sales;
```

---

<strike>**Common Table Expression**</strike>

You could organize the code a little better by using a CTE, although it is a bit more verbose:

```
WITH SalesInUS AS(
    SELECT ID
    FROM SalesType
    WHERE SalesType.Desc = 'US'
),

SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN Sales.TypeID IN SalesInUS THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
) 
FROM Sales;
```

But if this is often referenced, you are correct: a table would work better.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO #SalesInUS
    SELECT ID
    FROM SalesType
    WHERE SalesType.Desc = 'US'
```

Then you just join that table when you need it. Note I changed `SUM` to `COUNT` as well.

```
SELECT COUNT(Sales.TypeID)
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN #SalesInUS
ON Sales.TypeID = #SalesInUS.ID
```

Alternatively, you could also use a simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT COUNT(Sales.TypeID)
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN SalesType
ON Sales.TypeID = SalesType.ID
AND SalesType.Desc = 'US'
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN Sales.TypeID IN SalesInUS THEN 1` is not valid SQL. Would need to be `CASE WHEN Sales.TypeID IN (Select id from SalesInUs) THEN 1` Which is back to a subquery.

Comment: Good catch. I crossed out that section. Thanks for pointing this out.